# Using PHP-DI to inject variables into class methods automatically

Tags: php, dependency-injection, dependency-properties, php-di

I have been using PHP-DI and i wanted to enquire if there is a way to inject variables into various class methods automatically ie using autowiring.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use annotations, but that means you would have to annotate every method so it might not be as "automatic" as you hope.

You could also create a definition using [wildcards](http://php-di.org/doc/php-definitions.html#wildcards):

```
return [
    'MyProject\Controller\*' => DI\object()
        ->method('setSomething', DI\get('Foo')),
];
```

But honestly I would recommend not doing that and rather write injections manually. This is more explicit and easier to understand when re-reading the code 6 months later, or when a co-worker joins the project.